# Регулярные выражения. Получить обработчик события, который передан в метод addEventListener

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо в JS коде найти использование метода `addEventListener`.

Структура: `объект`.addEventListener('`событие`', `обработчик`, `другие_параметры_при_наличии`)

В качестве обработчика может быть как ранее объявленная функция (название), так и сама функция с объявлением (`function`).

Имеется следующее регулярное выражение

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
 
REX_ADD_EVENT_LISTENER = re.compile(
    r'\s*([A-Za-z0-9_]+).addEventListener\s*\('
    r'\s*[\'"`]([a-z]+)[\'"`]\s*,'
    r'\s*([A-Za-z0-9_]+|function\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*{\s*(.+?)})\s*'
    r',?\s*(.+)?\);?'
)
 
js_code = '''\
ctr_switch.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
 
ctr_switch.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
 
ctr_switch.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  if (flag) {
    setSignal("status", false);
    flag = false;
  }
}, false);'''
 
pprint(REX_ADD_EVENT_LISTENER.findall(js_code))
# [('ctr_switch', 'mousedown', 'onMouseDown', '', '', 'false'),
#  ('ctr_switch', 'mouseup', 'onMouseUp', '', '', 'false'),
#  ('ctr_switch', 'mouseout', 'function', '', '', '(')]
```

Если обработчиком является название функции, все работает нормально (хотя есть лишние пустые строки в результате), но вот вытащить функцию, которая определена с помощью `function`, не получается (нужно и тело этой функции).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как доработать регулярное выражение.

Стрелочные функции искать не нужно.

Простую функцию получаю с помощью следующего регулярного выражения:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

REX_FUNCTION = re.compile(
    r'(?ms)function\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*\([^)]*\)\s*{\s(.+?)^}')

js_code = '''\
function onMouseDown() {
  setSignal("status", true);
  flag = true;
}

ctr_switch.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);'''

pprint(REX_FUNCTION.findall(js_code))
#   название функции                       тело
# [('onMouseDown', '  setSignal("status", true);\n  flag = true;\n')]
```

Возможно получить примерно такой же результат для функции из addEventListener (без названия, конечно).

Comment: В параметрах функции точно может быть всё кроме `)`? Символы в теле функции тоже не проверяются?

Comment: @dIm0n, исхожу из того, что js код корректный. Кроме event (или e, evt, т.п.) вряд ли что-то будет.

Comment: А тело функции может быть пустым? `{}`?

Comment: @dIm0n, маловероятно, но думаю, что учесть это стоит. Точно должно быть `function() {}`. Дополнительно может быть параметр для функции и/или тело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот (основная проблема была в том, что `.` не находит переводы строк в теле функции (заменить на `[\s\S]` или добавить `s` флаг), но ещё упростил по мелочи):

```
\s*(\w+)\.addEventListener\s*\(\s*['\"`]([a-z]+)['\"`]\s*,\s*(function\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*{\s*[\s\S]*}|\w+)\s*,?\s*(.+)?\);?
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/vwlt8s/3

Сгенерированный код:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\s*(\w+)\.addEventListener\s*\(\s*['\"`]([a-z]+)['\"`]\s*,\s*(function\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*{\s*[\s\S]*}|\w+)\s*,?\s*(.+)?\);?"

test_str = ("ctr_switch.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);\n"
    "ctr_switch.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);\n"
    "ctr_switch.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {\n"
    "  if (flag) {\n"
    "    setSignal(\"status\", false);\n"
    "    flag = false;\n"
    "  }\n"
    "}, false);")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

А "пустые строки" в результате потому, что у функции в примере нет параметров, поэтому группа 4 пустая.